# Why use strcmp instead of == in C++?

Tags: c++, strcmp

I wonder my code works perfectly fine either using `strcmp` or simply `==` in C++ for comparing 2 char arrays. Can any one justify the reason of using `strcmp` instead of `==`;

Comment: Do you have an example of your code that works fine with both `==` and `strcmp`?

Comment: char abc1[10] = "Apple";
 char abc2[10]="Mango";
 if (abc1 == abc2)
  cout << "Equal ";
 else cout << "Not equal";

Comment: However now I get clear that == points to same location. i was confusing with NotEqual result.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`strcmp` compares the actual `C-string` content, while using `==` between two `C-string` is asking if these two `char` pointers point to the same position.

If we have some `C-string` defined as following:

```
char string_a[] = "foo";
char string_b[] = "foo";
char * string_c = string_a;
```

`strcmp(string_a, string_b) == 0` would return `true`, while `string_a == string_b` would return `false`. Only when "comparing" `string_a` and `string_c` using `==` would return `true`.

If you want to compare the actual contents of two `C-string` but not whether they are just alias of each other, use `strcmp`.

For a side note: if you are using `C++` instead of `C` as your question tag shows, then you should use `std::string`. For example,

```
std::string string_d = "bar";
std::string string_e = "bar";
```

then `string_d == string_e` would return `true`. `string_d.compare(string_e)` would return `0`, which is the `C++` version of `strcmp`.

Comment: note: this doesn't apply to std::string (in case ANYONE possibly doubted)

Comment: +1 beat me to it due to writing an example to show OP. No need to write another answer since you got it all already, just gonna leave the example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ce953c82def955ae) (with variables renamed to your versions).

Answer (score 2):

One advantage of using strcmp is that....it will return 
< 0 if str1 is less than str2

> 0 if str1 is greater than str2
>   and 0 if they are equal.

but if you use simply == it will only return either true or false.

Comment: it will return bool for different comparision.